# I am trying to create a function within google app scripts that parses a specific value from and places that value within my google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, xml-parsing, google-sheets

```
function getEarnings() {
  var url = 'http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=ntct';
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  var pageHtml = text.getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(pageHtml);
  var 1yrReturns = getElementsByClassName();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(EQUITY DB);
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  return (doc);
}
```

This is what I have thus far but I got stuck on XmlService portion of the code, this is for a very important class so PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I basically need my own version of the googlefinance() function!!!

Comment: you need to spend some time reading google apps script API. you've not explained what is the exact error/problem you're having. secondly, you've used methods like getActive() incorrectly. Put the example input set into your script for now, for testing (instead of using UrlFetch). Show what your code is producing as output. only then can we help you.

Comment: You can't use `getElementsByClassName()` in server side code.  That method can only be used in an HTML script tag.  It's a DOM method.  There *is* a `Document` class that you can use, after the XML is parsed, which has methods that are similar to DOM methods, but they are two different things.  The variable `1yrReturns` can not start with a number.  There needs to be a way to identify the element that you are trying to get.  I went to that website page and looked at it.  Are you trying to get a value out of the table?  What is the value?

Comment: I am trying to get the "EPS This Y" data from the table with is "25.6". I after your recommendations I spent some time going through the script API, but I'm still confused on how to execute the request and locate the specific data from the table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use importhtml. Enter this in the cell of your spreadsheet that you want 25.6% returned to:

```
=ArrayFormula( SUBSTITUTE( index(importhtml("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?  t=ntct","table",11),4,6) , "*" , "" ) )
```

To explain, if you enter the following, it will return the entire table:

```
=importhtml("http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=ntct","table",11)
```

index lets you pick the value you want from the table. In this case row 4, column 6 (the ,4,6). You can get any value from the table by its row and column.
The data is returned with asterisks before and after. The substitute replaces "*" with "".

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to input your suggestion but it seems to only return "top gainers" as its output, are there any changes that I should be making it prevent this issue?

Comment: I needed the sheet to read the output as a number which can be manipulated and by other formulas, do you know if there is a way to have the output converted so that I can use it in a formula (by the way I was able to correct the issue with "top gainers")

Comment: You should be able to use the output in a formula (25.60%). What error are you getting? You might check the format of the cell. I need more information to help you.

Comment: I ended up using the value function to convert the substitute into a number function...thank you so much for all of your help I submitted the assignment and it worked our well!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Could you please approve the answer? Thank you.